# ThreeJS WebXR modifies camera properties on re-entering VR the second/third/nth time

Tags: three.js, webxr

I'm facing a very weird experience with WebXR API. WebXR API changes the VR camera properties when I re-enter the VR. The camera somehow cuts my objects (shown below) when I re-enter the VR mode the second, third or nth time. [image]

It always works properly (shown below) when I enter VR first time.[image]

I would like to know why the objects are getting cut on the second/third/nth VR attempt and also how to debug WebXR immersive-vr camera properties.

I'm using very basic WebXR API codes as follows:

```
    window.onload=function()
{
    init();
    animate();
}

function init()
{   
    canvas = document.getElementById( 'vw_canvas' );
    canvas.width  = canvas.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
    canvasCssWidth = canvas.style.width;
    canvasCssHeight = canvas.style.height;
    group = new THREE.Object3D();//we create this to make it a parent of camera object.
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, canvas.width / canvas.height, 1, 10000 );
    group.rotation.order = 'XZY';//default is XYZ..we change this to XZY. because in case of XYZ when we rotate the object around its Y axis even the X and Z axis changes. so to avoid that we give higher priority to Z axis.
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    group.add(camera);
    scene.add(group);

    //add more 3D objects to scene

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true, powerPreference: "high-performance"});
    renderer.setPixelRatio( canvas.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( canvas.width, canvas.height );
    renderer.xr.enabled = true;
    renderer.xr.setReferenceSpaceType( 'local' );
    canvas.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var WEBVR = 
    {
        createButton: function ( renderer ) 
        {
            function showEnterXR( /*device*/ ) {

                var currentSession = null;

                function onSessionStarted( session ) 
                {
                    session.addEventListener( 'end', onSessionEnded );
                    renderer.xr.setSession( session );
                    vrButton.style.backgroundImage="url('icons/noVR.svg')";
                    document.getElementById("vr-button-tooltip").setAttribute("tooltip","Exit VR");
                    currentSession = session;
                    isVRpresenting=true;
                    openVRMenu();
                }

                function onSessionEnded( event ) 
                {
                    currentSession.removeEventListener( 'end', onSessionEnded );
                    renderer.xr.setSession( null );
                    vrButton.style.backgroundImage="url('icons/yesVR.svg')";
                    document.getElementById("vr-button-tooltip").setAttribute("tooltip","Enter VR");
                    currentSession = null;
                    isVRpresenting=false;
                    closeVRMenu();
                }

                vrButton.style.backgroundImage="url('icons/yesVR.svg')";
                document.getElementById("vr-button-tooltip").setAttribute("tooltip","Enter VR");
                isVRpresenting=false;
                vrButton.onclick = function () 
                {
                    if (runOnlyOnce) 
                    {
                        makeVRMenuItems();
                        runOnlyOnce=false;
                    }
                    if ( currentSession === null ) 
                    {
                        var sessionInit = { optionalFeatures: [ 'local-floor', 'bounded-floor' ] };
                        navigator.xr.requestSession( 'immersive-vr', sessionInit ).then( onSessionStarted );
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        currentSession.end();
                    }
                };

            }

            function showVRNotFound() 
            {
                vrButton.onclick = function () 
                {
                    //open VR popup that shows devices to use in order to exp VR
                };
                isVRavailable=false;
                vrButton.style.backgroundImage="url('icons/noVR.svg')";
                document.getElementById("vr-button-tooltip").setAttribute("tooltip","VR is not supported on your device");
                vrButton.onclick = null;
                // renderer.xr.setDevice( null );
                isVRpresenting=false;
            }

            if ( 'xr' in navigator ) 
            {
                isVRavailable=true;

                navigator.xr.isSessionSupported( 'immersive-vr' ).then( function ( supported ) {
                    supported ? showEnterXR() : showVRNotFound();
                } );

            } 

            else 
            {
                vrButton.onclick = function () 
                {
                    //open VR popup that shows devices to use in order to exp VR
                };
                isVRavailable=false;
                vrButton.style.backgroundImage="url('icons/noVR.svg')";
                document.getElementById("vr-button-tooltip").setAttribute("tooltip","VR is not supported on you device");
                isVRpresenting=false;
            }
        },
    };
    WEBVR.createButton( renderer );
}

function animate() 
{
    renderer.setAnimationLoop( animate );
    update();
}
function update() 
{
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the WebXR session takes the scene camera parameters for the first time it enters VR. Then, on second and subsequent visits the WebXR session sets the camera to default settings. Hence, in order to update the camera properties to be same as scene camera properties, we need to use this `session.updateRenderState({ depthFar: 10000 });`.In my case my scene camera had `depthFar=10000` but WebXR camera resets the `depthFar` property to 1000 in the second and subsequent visits in VR, which was the reason of frustum culling (image in question).